# Storage space issues

Tags: storage

I've changed the default install location from my Galaxy 2 but now I can't use the apps because it says:
"to open Facebook, you need more free storage on your phone. Please uninstall applications or remove other media from your phone to free up additional space"

I literally have deleted everything in my phone to try free up space... apps, messages, media

About to throw this phone against the wall...

What are my options here to try and get apps?

Comment: never getting an android again if this can't be fixed..

Comment: Have you looked at the Storage screen in Settings?  What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same steps you applied, Set default  InstallLocation to 0 which means the apps will be defaultly installed whether to phone memory or external SD card or set it to 1 to install apps to phone memory, but honestly I don't believe It's effective way since I didn't notice a big difference after applying that, but
If you root your phone you will be able to use Link2SD Plus app. (they call it Life Saver for those phones that come with small phone memory built in) which incredibly move the whole installed apps to SD using Linking method which makes the system thinks that the files of app you installed are still stored on phone memory but in fact they're in External SD memory saving for you so much memory of your phone. also you can set the default install location so easily through this app or other app requires root "except for some root apps even if you set the installation location to external they will be installed to phone memory eg. "BetterBatteryState" you will have to move them manually :) Or you can force apps to be moved to External using This app or Titanium Backup pro that both need Root privilges to work but Just a part of the app will be moved In other words, Link2SD is your best choice if you want to save a big size of your precious phone memory which obviously cannot be increased.